# Shiny Leaflet Map function not responding

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I created a marine mammal stranding map to respond when changing the date range and selecting different species. The code 'works' but the map function is not responding properly when sliderinput date range changes the circles on the map aren't responding. I'd appreciate any advice because I am at a loss after searching and looking at many other similar codes.

App.r

```
rm(list=ls()) 

#Libraries
library(shiny)
library(base)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(glue)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)

wdir=setwd(getwd())

options(shiny.reactlog = TRUE)

source("~/scs-docker/rserver/scripts-habs/HAB_Bulletin/Stranding_Data/Stranding_Data/Map_function.R")

#Read in Stranding Data
Stranding_Data = read_csv("~/scs-docker/rserver/scripts-habs/HAB_Bulletin/Stranding_Data/Stranding_Data/All_Strandings_2019-2021.csv")

#Clean up stranding data 
Stranding_Data2 = Stranding_Data %>%
  drop_na(Strand_Date) %>% #remove lines with no data 
  drop_na(Common_Name) %>% 
  #remove sea birds 
  filter(Common_Name != "Pacific loon",
         Common_Name != "Brandts cormorant",
         Common_Name != "Double-crested cormorant",
         Common_Name != "Western Grebe",
         Common_Name != "Common Loon",
         Common_Name != "Black-Vented Shearwater") %>% 
  select(Program,Strand_Date,Common_Name,Scientific_Name,Age_Class,Sex,Stranding_County,Stranding_City, Latitude,Longitude)

endDate = as.Date(max(Stranding_Data2$Strand_Date))
startDate = endDate - 30
minDate = as.Date(min(Stranding_Data2$Strand_Date))

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage( #fillPage
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Suspect Domoic Acid Marine Mammal Strandings", 
             windowTitle = "SCCOOS"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "Strand_Date",
                  label = "Stranding Date",
                  width = '100%',
                  min = minDate,
                  max = endDate,
                  value = c(startDate, endDate)),  
      # selectInput(
      #   inputId = "Program",
      #   label = "Stranding Center",
      #   choices = list("The Marine Mammal Center" = "TMMC",
      #                  "Channel Islands Marine Wildlife Institute" = "CIMWI",
      #                            "California Wildlife Center" = "CWC",
      #                            "Marine Animal Rescue" = "MAR",
      #                            "Marine Mammal Care Center Los Angeles" = "MMCC-LA",
      #                            "Pacific Marine Mammal Center"= "PMMC",
      #                            "SeaWorld San Diego"= "SeaWorld")),
      selectInput( #selectInput checkboxGroupInput
        inputId = "Common_Name",
        label= "Species",
        choices=sort(unique(Stranding_Data2$Common_Name)),
        multiple = T,
        selected = "California Sea Lion"),
      h6("Disclaimer: These are suspected marine mammal strandings due to domoic acid (DA) toxicosis. Species exposed to DA often result in seizures, epilepsy, cardiomyopathy, and death depending upon the ingested dose. Neuroscopy are required to confirm cases of DA toxicosis.", align = "left")
    ),
    
    # Show a map of the generated distribution and table of data 
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Map", leafletOutput(outputId = "mymap", height = 600)), #height = "1000px", width = "100%" #height=1000
        tabPanel("Table",DT::dataTableOutput("mytable", height = 600))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #create map
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    #leaflet function to create the basemap 
    Stranding_Map(Stranding_Data2)
  }) 
  
  observe({
    #leafletproxy function for circles 
    Add_Circles(Stranding_Data2, 
                group=input$Common_Name, 
                daterange = input$Strand_Date)
  })
  
  #create table
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    
    daterange = input$Strand_Date
    endDate = daterange[2]
    startDate = daterange[1]
    
    Stranding_Data2 %>% 
       filter(Common_Name %in% input$Common_Name,
              Strand_Date>=startDate & Strand_Date<=endDate) 
    
    datatable(Stranding_Data2) 
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Stranding Map Function

```
Stranding_Map = function(data){ 
  
  species_name = c("California Sea Lion", 
                   "Northern Fur Seal",
                   "Guadalupe Fur Seal",
                   "Common Bottlenose Dolphin",
                   "Short-Beaked Common Dolphin",
                   "Striped dolphin",
                   "North Pacific Right Whale",
                   "Gray Whale")
  my_palette = c("#FF0000FF", "#FFBF00FF", "#80FF00FF", "#00FF40FF", "#00FFFFFF", "#0040FFFF", "#8000FFFF", "#FF00BFFF")
  #previewColors(colorFactor(my_palette, levels = species_Name), species_Name)
  factpal = colorFactor(palette=my_palette, domain=species_name)
  
  leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.OceanBasemap) %>%
    setView(lng = -122, lat = 38, zoom = 5) %>%
    addLegend(
      pal= factpal,
      values = species_name, 
      opacity = 1,
      position = "topright",
      title="Species Name",
      layerId  = "color-legend")
}

Add_Circles = function(data, group, daterange){ 
  
  endDate = daterange[2]
  startDate = daterange[1]
  
  data = data %>% 
    filter(Common_Name %in% group,
           Strand_Date>=startDate & Strand_Date<=endDate)
  
  Common_Name = c("California Sea Lion", "Northern Fur Seal","Guadalupe Fur Seal",
                   "Common Bottlenose Dolphin","Short-Beaked Common Dolphin","Striped dolphin",
                   "North Pacific Right Whale","Gray Whale")
  my_palette = c("#FF0000FF", "#FFBF00FF", "#80FF00FF", "#00FF40FF", "#00FFFFFF", "#0040FFFF", "#8000FFFF", "#FF00BFFF")
  factpal2 = colorFactor(palette=my_palette, levels=Common_Name)
  
  leafletProxy("mymap") %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(data=data,  
                     color= ~factpal2(Common_Name),
                     fillOpacity = 1,
                     weight = 0.5,
                     stroke= 'none',
                     label=paste(
                       data$Strand_Date,",",
                       "Rehab Center:",data$Program,",",
                       data$Common_Name,""),
                       #"County:",data$Stranding_County,",",
                       #"City:",data$Stranding_City,""),
                     popup=paste(
                       "Stranding Date:",data$Strand_Date,"<br>",
                       "Rehab Center:", data$Program,"<br>",
                       "Species:", data$Common_Name,"<br>",
                       "County:", data$Stranding_County,"<br>",
                       "City:", data$Stranding_City,"<br>"),
                     lng=~Longitude, 
                     lat=~Latitude) 
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested in helping if possible, but I can't run the code you have because I don't have your csv. Could you maybe post part of your data, or maybe just create a fake data frame which shows the problem so others can test it? Thanks!

Comment: You have `Stranding_Data2 %>% filter...` that isn't storing the result after filtering...did you mean `Stranding_Data2 <- Stranding_Data2 %>% filter...`?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my error by updating my server function! Thanks for the advice!

```
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #create map
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    #leaflet function to create the basemap 
    daterange = input$Strand_Date
    endDate = daterange[2]
    startDate = daterange[1]
    print(startDate)
    print(input$endDate)
    print(input$Common_name)
    x = Stranding_Data2 %>%
      filter(Common_Name %in% input$Common_Name,
              Strand_Date>=startDate & Strand_Date<=endDate)
    Stranding_Map(x)
  }) 
  
  observe({
    #leafletproxy function for circles 
    Add_Circles(Stranding_Data2, 
                group=input$Common_Name, 
                daterange = input$Strand_Date)
  })
  
  #create table
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    daterange = input$Strand_Date
    endDate = daterange[2]
    startDate = daterange[1]
    print(startDate)
    print(input$endDate)
    print(input$Common_name)
    x = Stranding_Data2 %>%
      filter(Common_Name %in% input$Common_Name,
             Strand_Date>=startDate & Strand_Date<=endDate)
  })
}
```